# What should these rails 2 routes look like in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

url is mysite.com/lists/student where lists is the rails application installed on a sub domain redirected to the rails app.

rails 2 was:

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.connect "student", :controller => 'student', :action => 'index'
```

for rails 3 I've tried these:

```
 match "/student/" => "student#index"
 match 'student/:id', :to => 'student#index'
 match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format);
```

but not working.

"rake routes" gives no output.

Comment: By "`rake routes` gives no output" do you mean no output whatsoever? In that case you might not have properly migrated your project. Take a look at this post: http://x-aeon.com/wp/2012/12/19/migrating-big-applications-from-rails-2-to-rails-3/

Comment: Anyway, `match "students" => "students#index"` should work.

Comment: I'd love to use the rails_upgrade plugin to make migration easier, but I'm on a shared hosting solution and don't think I have permissions to change the ruby version so can't switch back to 1.8 from 1.9.3.  I've updated the .bashrc and .bash_profile to point at 1.8 but the ruby version is stuck on 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `match`, you have to specify which HTTP verb is being used.  See [the routing documentation about this subject](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) for more details.  A quick example is:

```
match '/student', to: 'student#index', via: :index
```

I'd recommend changing your routes to be based on the above Rails Routing guide.  For example, assuming these are `get` requests:

```
get '/student', to: 'student#index'
get 'student/:id', to: 'student#show'
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```